# Proc UCM Forecast Series

Tags: time-series, forecasting, sas, unobserved-components-model

I'm forecasting a data series with one time dependent variable (GDP) and one 0 1 time indicator "Flag" (0 starting at February 2014, 1 before that). When I use `proc ucm` with the below options, it starts the predicted series forecast 12 periods before the end of the historical period. When I take out the split flag, the forecast series begins 5 periods after the start of the historical period. I can't seem to figure out what about the data/code is making the difference, but I would like to have predicted values back to the start of the data to compare with actuals.

```
PROC UCM DATA=m_data;
    ID date INTERVAL=MONTH;
    MODEL dep_var=

             GDP
             Flag

             ;
    LEVEL CHECKBREAK VARIANCE=0 NOEST ;
    SLOPE VARIANCE=0 NOEST ;
    RANDOMREG 
            GDP
                ;

    NLOPTIONS MAXITER=200;
    ESTIMATE skiplast=2;
    FORECAST BACK=2 LEAD=2 OUTFOR=DATA;

RUN;
```

Comment: At what observation does your split flag has 1.

Comment: Just saw my typo - it is 0 starting Feb 2014, 1 before that

Comment: What is the date at which the observation ends?

Comment: Observation period ends March 2015

Comment: As I suspected,The reason why the model forecasts 12 period before the end of historical data is that that's when it encounters 0 in your split flag first time, if you want to test this change the split fag starting attend 2013 you will get forecast for 24 months before the end of historical data in any rate why would you want to forecast the historical vales?

Comment: Thanks - although without the split flag, the predicted values forecast begins 5 periods after the start of the data. With the split flag, it begins 2 periods after the start of the 0's. So when Split flag is set to 0 starting march 2013, predictions start may 2013. My real question is what about the way SAS calculates my predictions is causing it to react to 0 in the split flag. And why when I take the split flag out does it start 5 periods after the start. My guess is that it has something to do with calculating the time varying coefficients, but I really can't this in documentation.

Comment: It starts in May 2013 because you have either skip last or back option, try removing and rerun the code